# How to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }{a_n}^{b_n}=\alpha ^\beta $?

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }{a_n}=\alpha (\neq 0) $ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }{b_n}=\beta$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }{a_n}^{b_n}=\alpha ^\beta $?

I unconsciously used this but I realized I'd never seen this theorem before. Is it true?

Comment: If $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$ then it is true.

Comment: See also: [convergent sequence $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$, does it convergent $\{ {a_n}^{b_n} \}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1390843)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that
$$a_n^{b_n}=e^{b_n\log(a_n)}$$
so by the **continuity of the exponential and logarithmic functions** you have the result, of course with the **assumption** $\boldsymbol{a_n>0}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha>0}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that we can use the fact of convergent sequences product and that
$$e^{b_n \cdot \log a_n}$$ 
converges when $n \rightarrow \infty$.